# Why is Cocoapods adding preserved files to compilation?

Tags: c++, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I have a podspec for a project that contains an embedded C++ library. The podspec looks like this (with the source being local until I get it working and push to GitHub):

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name          = "LibName"
  s.version       = "1.0.0"
  s.summary       = "Summary"
  s.license       = "BSD"
  s.homepage      = "https://homepage.com"
  s.author        = { "Dov Frankel" => "dov@email.com" }
  s.source        = { :git => "/Users/Dov/PathTo/LocalLibrary" }
  s.ios.deployment_target = "5.0"
  s.osx.deployment_target = "10.7"
  s.requires_arc = false
  s.source_files = "Classes/*.{mm,m,h}",
                   "Libraries/unrar/*.hpp",
                   "Libraries/lib/fileA.cpp",
                   "Libraries/lib/fileB.cpp",
  s.preserve_paths = "Libraries/lib/fileC.cpp",
                     "Libraries/lib/fileD.cpp"
end
```

In the LibName project that gets created, the list of compiled sources includes fileA, fileB, fileC, and fileD. Why is that? The `preserve_paths` files should only be preserved, not compiled.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! Remove the trailing comma from fileB.cpp, which apparently causes the `preserve_paths` to get concatenated onto the end of `source_files`.